# GraphQL Dynamically build fragment from array

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, graphql, apollo

Following other answers, it seems that the recommended way of building dynamic query is to use fragments in this manner:

```
const series1Q = gql`
  fragment series1 on timeseriesDataQuery {
    series1: timeseriesData(sourceId: "source1") {
      data {
        time
        value
      }
    }
  }
}

const series2Q = gql`
  fragment series2 on timeseriesDataQuery {
    series2: timeseriesData(sourceId: "source2") {
      data {
        time
        value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And joining them with:

```
export const mainQuery = gql`
    query fetchData {
      ...series1 
      ...series2
    }
    ${series1Q}
    ${series2Q}
`
```

However in my case, I do not know the number of items as the user can add a number of item to it so I end up with an array eg,

```
const series = 
[
    gql`
        fragment series1 on timeseriesDataQuery {
            series1: timeseriesData(sourceId: "source1") {
                data {
                    time
                    value
                }
            }
        }
    `,
    gql`
        fragment series2 on timeseriesDataQuery {
            series2: timeseriesData(sourceId: "source2") {
                data {
                    time
                    value
                }
            }
        }
    `
]
```

I cant seem to join them in the gql func, have tried different ways eg,

```
export const mainQuery = gql`
    ${...series}
    query fetchData {
      ...series1 
      ...series2
    }
`
```

or

```
export const mainQuery = gql`
    {...series}
    query fetchData {
      ...series1 
      ...series2
    }
`
```

and all seems to be in the wrong format,

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-germain-hs16ti?file=/src/App.tsx

Have anyone managed to create a dynamic query from array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think the main issue was with the fragment piece being parsed to [object Object] when using the map func: `${query.sql}` or other equivalent,

A workaround was to get the fragment query using **query.sql.loc.source.body**

Example of a working example using @Dakeyras answer:

```
const series = 
[{
    name: 'series1',
    sql: gql`
        fragment series1 on timeseriesDataQuery {
            series1: timeseriesData(sourceId: "source1") {
                data {
                    time
                    value
                }
            }
        }
    `,
},
{
    name: 'series2',
    sql: gql`
        fragment series2 on timeseriesDataQuery {
            series2: timeseriesData(sourceId: "source2") {
                data {
                    time
                    value
                }
            }
        }
    `
}]

export const mainQuery = gql`
    query fetchData {
      ${series.map(query => `...${query.name}`).join('\n')}
    }
    ${series.map(query => `${query.sql.loc?.source.body}`).join('\n')}
`
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
export const mainQuery = gql`
    query fetchData {
      ...series1 
      ...series2
    }
    ${series1Q}
    ${series2Q}
`
```

In this snippet of code, what you are essentially doing is listing each fragment name and then each fragment. The way to do this for an unknown number of fragments is by iterating over the fragments, which would look something like this (note that the `series` array now has the fragment name stored separately):

```js
const series = 
[{
    name: 'series1',
    sql: gql`
        fragment series1 on timeseriesDataQuery {
            series1: timeseriesData(sourceId: "source1") {
                data {
                    time
                    value
                }
            }
        }
    `,
},
{
    name: 'series2',
    sql: gql`
        fragment series2 on timeseriesDataQuery {
            series2: timeseriesData(sourceId: "source2") {
                data {
                    time
                    value
                }
            }
        }
    `
}]

export const mainQuery = gql`
    query fetchData {
      ${series.map(query => `...${query.name}`).join('\n')}
    }
    ${series.map(query => query.sql).join('\n')}
`
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, i think there might be a mistake in series being an object and using .map to iterate it, will try solution tomorrow!

Comment: @BloopieBloops I have edited the answer somewhat, this should now work as expected

Comment: hello, I tried the solution and got the same error as i was having, putting this line  ${series.map(query => query.sql).join('\n')} in gql`<here>`  gives uncaught graphQL exception unexpected "[", printing this line as string I get, "[Object object]"

Comment: have added a codesandbox in main post to replicate error